# Expensive SPARQL operations, a comparative guideline

Tags: sparql

There is trade off between running SPARQL queries and the code you write the clean up the results.
**Complex query:** `Pros`: *Get clean/efficient results, less code for cleanup* `Cons:` *timeout error, long processing time* .
 I know one can not generalize it but wanted to compare combing **subqueries (UNION,...), Filters and Aggregates** and see which one is a more expensive operation in case of time out.
 For example I am running this query from Japanese SPARQL endpoint (I removed some part of it).

```
SELECT ?film ?dblink ?filmType (group_concat(?actors ; separator = "|") AS ?actorset) (group_concat(?country ; separator = "|") AS ?countryset) (group_concat(?releaseDate ; separator = "|") AS ?releasedateset) (group_concat(?language ; separator = "|") AS ?languageset) (group_concat(?genre ; separator = "|") AS ?genreset) ?numberOfEpisodes  ?numberOfSeasons
WHERE {
     {?film a dbpedia-owl:Film } UNION {?film a dbpedia-owl:TelevisionShow } UNION {?film a dbpedia-owl:Cartoon } UNION {?film a dbpedia-owl:TelevisionSeason } .
     {?film a ?filmType  } .Filter(regex(?filmType,"(?:TelevisionSeason|Cartoon|Film|TelevisionShow)")) .
     OPTIONAL { {?film dbpedia-owl:starring ?actors} UNION {?film dbpprop:starring ?actors}  }. OPTIONAL { ?film dbpedia-owl:country ?country  }.  OPTIONAL { {?film dbpprop:genre ?genre} UNION  { ?film dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre  } }. OPTIONAL { {?film dbpprop:language ?language} UNION {?film dbpedia-owl:language ?language}  }. OPTIONAL { ?film dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?wikiPageID   } .
     OPTIONAL {?film owl:sameAs ?dblink . Filter (strstarts( str(?dblink), 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/'))}
 } LIMIT 5
```

It timesout. What is more efficient (to avoid timeouts) to remove and process the results later in my code?
**1- Aggregates** (group_concat)
**2- Filters:** post process it in my code
**3- Subqueries**: remove some of the subqueries ( Optional vs Union) and do them in another query

Comment: Your query is about three pages wide; most users probably aren't going to read it.  A bunch of stuff in your query can be cleaned up using value blocks and property paths.  Optimization questions like this might be off-topic since they're rather broad (there could be lots of possible answers).

Answer (score 6):

Optimization questions are tough, especially when endpoints can impose different limits.  That said, there are at least a few things that can simplify this query a lot.

### Finding individuals of certain classes

```
{?film a dbpedia-owl:Film } UNION {?film a dbpedia-owl:TelevisionShow } UNION {?film a dbpedia-owl:Cartoon } UNION {?film a dbpedia-owl:TelevisionSeason } .
```

should really be:

```
values ?filmType { dbpedia-owl:Film
                   dbpedia-owl:Television
                   dbpedia-owl:Cartoon
                   dbpedia-owl:TelevisionSeason }
?film a ?filmType
```

That will handle all the fixed types.  The next part

```
filter(regex(?filmType,"(?:TelevisionSeason|Cartoon|Film|TelevisionShow)"))
```

seems designed to find anything that has a type that includes one of those strings.  That's potentially got to iterate over all the individuals, and over all their types, and then run a regular expression on all them.  Ugh.  Better would be to find the ontology classes with names that match that stuff, and then retrieve individuals of those classes.

(Note that here and above, Cartoon might refer to non-film things;  e.g., political cartoons in a newspaper.)

That said, a better solution might be to browse the class hierarchy a bit and see if there's some common superclass of the things that you're interested in.  If something is a member of a subclass, then it's a member of the superclasses, too, so you can save some querying that way.

### Finding optional properties

```
OPTIONAL { {?film dbpedia-owl:starring ?actors} UNION
           {?film dbpprop:starring ?actors}           } .
OPTIONAL { ?film dbpedia-owl:country ?country  } . 
OPTIONAL { {?film dbpprop:genre ?genre } UNION
           {?film dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre  } }.
OPTIONAL { {?film dbpprop:language ?language} UNION
           {?film dbpedia-owl:language ?language}  }.
OPTIONAL { ?film dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?wikiPageID   } .
```

There's not too much that you that can do to clean these up, except that:

1. dbpedia-owl:properties have much cleaner data than dbpprop: properties, so you'll get better results if you just skip the dbpprop: properties.
2. That said, if you do want to get values based on more than property, just use the alternation construct in property paths.  E.g., The first optional block becomes:

   ```
    OPTIONAL { {?film dbpedia-owl:starring|dbpprop:starring ?actors }
   ```

   which gets rid of the union, and makes your query a bit simpler.

### Matching resources begin with a given namespace

```
OPTIONAL { ?film owl:sameAs ?dblink .
           Filter (strstarts( str(?dblink), 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/'))}
```

This isn't bad, although owl:sameAs is transitive and reflexive, so you should probably let the link go in either direction.  Also (and this doesn't matter so much), you can make your query a little more maintainable by using `str` to get the prefix.  Thus:

```
prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

optional { ?film (owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)* ?dblink .
           filter (strstarts( str(?dblink), str(:dbpedia) ) }
```

### Aggregate functions

```
SELECT
  ?film ?dblink ?filmType
  (group_concat(?actors ; separator = "|") AS ?actorset)
  (group_concat(?country ; separator = "|") AS ?countryset)
  (group_concat(?releaseDate ; separator = "|") AS ?releasedateset)
  (group_concat(?language ; separator = "|") AS ?languageset)
  (group_concat(?genre ; separator = "|") AS ?genreset)
  ?numberOfEpisodes ?numberOfSeasons
WHERE { … }
LIMIT 5
```

You're using a number of `group_concat` aggregates.  That's probably not much a problem by itself, since it's just iterating through each group and building a string.  That's linear in the number of results (before the group) that you have, so it shouldn't be too expensive.  However, it's *not* legal to select both group and non-grouped variables.  If you're going to select five variables without an aggregate, you need to explicitly use a group by:

```
SELECT
  ?film ?dblink ?filmType
  (group_concat(?actors ; separator = "|") AS ?actorset)
  (group_concat(?country ; separator = "|") AS ?countryset)
  (group_concat(?releaseDate ; separator = "|") AS ?releasedateset)
  (group_concat(?language ; separator = "|") AS ?languageset)
  (group_concat(?genre ; separator = "|") AS ?genreset)
  ?numberOfEpisodes ?numberOfSeasons
WHERE {  }
GROUP BY ?film ?dblink ?filmType ?numberOfEpisodes ?numberOfSeasons
LIMIT 5
```

I'm aware that Virtuoso may accept query without the explicit group by, but it *is* required in SPARQL. In fact, I answered a recent answers.semanticweb.com question, [Variable used when already in-scope error](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/29643/variable-used-when-already-in-scope-error) that touched on this point.  It's a good idea to check your queries in [sparql.org's validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html).

Comment: Great comments, I appreciate it. How about the use group_concat, I just don't see anyway around it but is it an expensive operation?

Comment: @user1848018 Your query as written isn't actually legal.  See the updates to my answer.  The group_concat probably isn't very expensive (it's just output processing), but you should have a group by in the query to make it legal.